# Display .txt file in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, text, filereader

I am trying to display a particular text file in JTextArea but eclipse keeps showing me an error.

```
try {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("Student.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    JTextArea.read(br,null);
    br.close();
    JTextArea.requestFocus();
    }
catch(Exception e){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong");
}
```

this is the code i am using and the error i get is

*"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method read(Reader, Object) from the type JTextComponent"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create object for JTextArea  class.
Please try with below code:

```
FileReader reader;
        try {

            reader = new FileReader("Student.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); 

             JTextArea area = new JTextArea();


                area.read(br,null);
                br.close();

             area.requestFocus();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```